# mlock blocked by FIFO thread of a different process on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, real-time, virtual-memory

I am working on some real-time programs that require mlock and FIFO scheduling policy for fast paths.

I am running two processes on Ubuntu 16.04 with 12 CPU cores, and I assigned the fast paths of these processes to different cores.

Process 1 starts normally and pins its fast thread to a CPU and sets the scheduling policy to FIFO on this thread.

When process 2 starts, before its fast thread is created, it tries to call mlock.

Then, process 2 is stuck.

I attached gdb to process 2, and the call stack seems to be inside the mlock function.

If I remove the FIFO setting on process 1, both processes can run normally.

My suspicion is that mlock is trying to access some kernel resources that is acquired by the fast thread of process 1.

So it is blocked and put on wait indefinitely.

Does anyone know exactly what it is waiting for?

I have observed this problem on two similar IBM servers with Ubuntu.

But, on a Supermicro machine with a Redhat Linux, this issue didn't occur.

Thanks for any hint or solution!

Comment: Welcome to SO. **:)** I suggest going over [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order for someone to help you your question needs to be clear, contain actual code, and indicate that you already did research on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SCHED_FIFO process that completely occupied a CPU such that non-sched-fifo threads never get scheduled on that CPU, some in-kernel algorithms may stop working, depending on kernel version/configuration.

Try booting with rcutree.kthread_prio=N where N is larger than SCHED_FIFO priority of your thread.

Try playing with /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us

Try to get in-kernel backtrace of hanged mlock() to understand where it is waiting - this may get a hint.  For that, use /proc/pid/stack (if your kernel is compiled with CONFIG_STACKTRACE) or maybe 'echo t > /proc/sysrq-trigger'